# How to Click on a Checkbox Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, checkbox

My goal is to check a checkbox on a website. The html:

```
<label class="checkbox" for="are_terms_agreed">
<input name="terms" id="are_terms_agreed" class="checkbox__input required-entry validate-checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox">
<span class="checkbox__span">
<i class="checkbox__icon"></i>
</span>
<span class="checkbox__title">
I have read and agree to the 
<span class="signup__label-terms">
<a onclick="return false;" href="https://shop.adidas.ae/en/help/terms-conditions.html" class="js-dialog-btn" data-target="js-dialog-terms">
Terms &amp; Conditions
</a>
for website use
</span>
</span>
</label>
```

Original link: https://shop.adidas.ae/en/checkout/onepage/ (you might have to add a shoe to a cart and proceed the checkout process to view the page I'm viewing)

I have tried a few different ways to accomplish this.
Firstly, I have tried to access the

`IWebElement termsandconditions2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[@class = 'checkbox']//label[@for = 'are_terms_agreed']"));`

I get the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll
>   Additional information: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//label[@class = 'checkbox']//label[@for = 'are_terms_agreed']"}

I have also tried:

`IWebElement termsandconditions = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[class*='checkbox__span']"));`

This is basically clicking on the actual "check" icon, rather than checking the whole box as I tried before. When I run this, I get the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException' occurred in WebDriver.dll Additional information: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

I have tried using scroll down code, nothing happens.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: It has 'ID', use `driver.FindElement(By.Id("are_terms_agreed")).Click();`

Comment: Error : Additional information: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Comment: Try driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#co-terms-form > label:nth-child(2) > span.checkbox__span > i"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the coordinates click event. Try it.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*[@id='co-terms-form']/label[1]/span[1]")), 2, 2).Click().Perform();
```

Or:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*[@id='co-terms-form']/label[1]/span[1]").CLick()
```

Comment: Hi Turgut, what do I put inside the [1]? Or do I just leave it?

Comment: just leave it :). the "[1]" index count. But all web element of xpaths are different.

Comment: Nevermind, completely solved the problem. Thank you so much man!

Comment: you are wellcome :)